# node.updateInfo is not a function while appending node in extjs

Tags: extjs4, treepanel

I am trying to load data into an extjs 4 `TreeStore` but while appending node, I am getting `node.updateInfo is not a function` error.

My model classes are as follows :

**Dimension.js**

```
Ext.define('ilp.model.Dimension', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    require : [
        'ilp.model.DimensionLevel'
    ],
    fields : [
        'actualName', 
        'displayName'
    ],
    hasMany : {model : 'ilp.model.DimensionLevel', name : 'dimensionLevels'}
});
```

**DimensionLevel.js**

```
Ext.define('ilp.model.DimensionLevel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
        {name : 'name', type : 'string'},
        {name : 'totalTrainees', type : 'int'}
    ]
});
```

and tree store code is as follows :

```
Ext.define('ilp.store.DimensionTree', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    requires : [
        'ilp.model.Dimension',
        'ilp.model.DimensionLevel'
    ],
    model : 'ilp.model.Dimension',

    root: {
    name: 'Dimensions'
    },

    proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/pentaho/content/cda/doQuery',
    reader: {
            type: 'pentahoReader',
        root: 'resultset'
    },
    extraParams: {
        path: 'RINXDashboards%2FCDAs%2FILP_Employee_Qeries.cda',
        dataAccessId:'Get_All_Levels_From_All_Dimensions',
        userid : 'joe',
        password : 'password'
    }
    },

    listeners: {
    append : function(parentNode, newNode, index, options) {
            if(newNode.get('text') != 'Root') {
        console.log('newNode text value = ' + newNode.get('text'));
        newNode.set('checked', null);
        newNode.set('expandable', true);
        if(Ext.ClassManager.getName(newNode) == "ilp.model.Dimension") {
            newNode.set('expanded', true);
        newNode.set('text', newNode.get('displayName'));
        if(newNode.dimensionLevels().getCount() > 0) {
            newNode.dimensionLevels().each(function(level) {
            newNode.appendChild(level);
        });
        } else {
        newNode.set('leaf', true);
              }
        }else if(Ext.ClassManager.getName(newNode) == "ilp.model.DimensionLevel") {
            newNode.set('leaf', true);
        newNode.set('text', newNode.get('name'));
        }
    }
      }
    }
});
```

I am getting above error on following line  : 
`newNode.dimensionLevels().each(function(level) {`

while debugging I have found that `updateInfo()` method of `newNode` is `undefined`.

Can anyone please tell me why this error is coming? I am totally clueless now !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this is caused by the bug EXTJSIV-6051

see [Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?199888-4.1.0-updateInfo-is-not-a-function-when-adding-a-model-instance-to-a-node) for further infos

Comment: thanks.. I had to switch back to ExtJS 4.0.1 version because of this single bug...

Comment: I found [4.1.1 RC1](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205564-Ext-JS-4.1.1-RC1-Now-Available) ... have a try

Comment: I was just too optimistic http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?205564-Ext-JS-4.1.1-RC1-Now-Available&p=811460&viewfull=1#post811460

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from :

```
root: {
   name: 'Dimensions'
},
```

root attribute must be of type: Ext.data.Model/Ext.data.NodeInterface/Object. So try to replace 'root' attribute by this:

```
root: {
    text: "Dimensions",
    leaf: false
}
```

Check Sencha doc for more information: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-cfg-root